# If A, B are vectors, what does C = (A|B) mean?

Tags: matrices

I'm having trouble understanding some notation.

We are given V = (2,1) and W = (1,0), and then the matrix B = (V|W) = ((2,-1), (1,0))

What does the | mean?
Thanks!

EDIT: Here is some context, we are given A = ((-1,4),(-1,3))

We need B s.t. AB = B((1,1),(0,1))

V is an eigenvector of A and W is a linearly independent vector to V.

Comment: Apparently the sheffer stroke here means arrange the vectors in columns comprising the matrix.

Comment: Is the minus sign a typo?

Comment: Must be a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Often, the notation $(A|B)$ means the augmentation where $A$ and $B$ are matrices of proper order. Assume$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots &a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots &a_{2n}\\\vdots&\ddots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots &a_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$$and $$B=\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&b_{12}&\cdots &b_{1n}\\b_{21}&b_{22}&\cdots &b_{2n}\\\vdots&\ddots\\b_{n1}&b_{n2}&\cdots &b_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$$therefore $$(A|B)=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots &a_{1n}&b_{11}&b_{12}&\cdots &b_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots &a_{2n}&b_{21}&b_{22}&\cdots &b_{2n}\\\vdots&\ddots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots &a_{nn}&b_{n1}&b_{n2}&\cdots &b_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$$